# "pip install" permission denied on Mac

Tags: python

I tried to install the base65536 module, by typing this into Terminal:

`pip install base65536`

Yet it produced this error:

Collecting base65536
  Using cached base65536-0.1.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from base65536)
Installing collected packages: base65536
  Running setup.py install for base65536 ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/2h/n5zk2_w50273k4hdxw8l05240000gn/T/pip-build-tl_DyR/base65536/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/2h/n5zk2_w50273k4hdxw8l05240000gn/T/pip-ZZqmm6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib
    creating build/lib/base65536
    copying base65536/**about**.py -> build/lib/base65536
    copying base65536/**init**.py -> build/lib/base65536
    copying base65536/core.py -> build/lib/base65536
    running install_lib
    creating /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/base65536
    error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/base65536': Permission denied

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/2h/n5zk2_w50273k4hdxw8l05240000gn/T/pip-build-tl_DyR/base65536/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/2h/n5zk2_w50273k4hdxw8l05240000gn/T/pip-ZZqmm6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/2h/n5zk2_w50273k4hdxw8l05240000gn/T/pip-build-tl_DyR/base65536/

How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you're not using any virtualenv. Are you deliberately trying to install to your system-level Python packages? Are you aware of the complexities that can arise from doing so?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by I don't have a virtualenv. Im just trying to install that python module. Am I missing files? Because I haven't been able to get to my Python files at all either.

Comment: Did you do anything special to install Python? What is your motivation for installing this library? Unfortunately, since macOS includes a version of Python and uses it for certain OS-level tasks simply `pip install`ing things at the OS level can result in complications.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

When it says `Permission Denied` that means that you are not an administrator on your computer and therefore cannot do this. Try running as administrator. If you are using windows, right click on app and select 'Run as Administrator'. If you are using mac, and you are not the administrator on your computer, type `su (Whatever the name of the admin. user is)`

For example, `su adminUsername`

Then type

`pip install base65536`

Comment: I am assuming you mean typing this into the app called Terminal

Comment: Bear in mind that this might cause problems, particularly if the OP is using whatever Python shipped with macOS. It's not a great idea to `pip install` with admin privileges without understanding the full implications. It would be helpful to know how Python was installed on this machine.

Comment: I managed to get it to work, I just had to do `sudo pip install <module name>`  on the admin account of my computer. How can I mark this issue as resolved?

Comment: @Programmer157 click the checkmark by the answer that helped you

Answer (score -1):

Thats because you dont have admin permissions.
try this
`sudo pip install base65536`

Comment: I'm getting tired of saying this, but simply forcing an OS-level `pip install` can cause problems at the OS level. We need more context for what the OP is trying to do in order to answer properly.